# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with

Tags: api, google-calendar-api, uncaught-exception

A core php website is integrated with google calendar API. A web form data collected and to be updated to google calendar. Inspite of having all the date format using **DATE_ATOM,mktime()** I am facing this issue.

**How to fix Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException'?**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with
>   message 'Expected response code 200, got 400 [Line 1, Column 659,
>   element gd:when] Badly formatted datetime' in
>   /home/website/public_html/zend/lib/Zend/Gdata/App.php:700 
>   Stack trace:#0 /home/website/public_html/zend/lib/Zend/Gdata.php(219): Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('POST', 'http://www.goog...',
>   Array, 'performHttpRequest('POST', 'http://www.goog...', Array,
>   'post(Object(Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventEntry), 'http://www.goog...',
>   NULL, NULL, Array) #3
>   /home/website/public_html/zend/lib/Zend/Gdata/Calendar.php(165):
>   Zend_Gdata_App->insertEntry(Object(Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventEntry),
>   'http://www.goog...', 'Zend_Gdata_Cale...') #4
>   /home/website/public_html/add-session.php(297):
>   Zend_Gdata_Calendar->insertEvent(Object(Zend_Gdata_C in
>   /home/website/public_html/zend/lib/Zend/Gdata/App.php on line 700

NONE OF THE BELOW LINKS HELPED ME
[Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561307/uncaught-exception-zend-gdata-app-httpexception)
[YouTube PHP API - Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562083/youtube-php-api-zend-gdata-app-httpexception)
[Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954202/fatal-error-uncaught-exception-runtimeexception)
[Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' in PHPExcel classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863400/fatal-error-uncaught-exception-exception-in-phpexcel-classes)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-contacts-api/IFHANnTWzIM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any html entities or space, start time or end time then you will end up with this issue. Make sure that there are no html entities or space in the below line of codes.

> $start = date(DATE_ATOM, mktime($_POST['sdate_hh'],
> $_POST['sdate_ii'], 0, $_POST['sdate_mm'], $_POST['sdate_dd'],
> $_POST['sdate_yy']));
>
> $end = date(DATE_ATOM,
> mktime($_POST['edate_hh'], $_POST['edate_ii'], 0, $_POST['edate_mm'],
> $_POST['edate_dd'], $_POST['edate_yy']));

Hence the issue is solved.